# context.application.createDocument doesn't work

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I want to fill content to a new document (`myNewDoc`) and not the current document in context.

The following code however is only able to change the content of the current document:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(getDocumentAsBase64());
    context.load(myNewDoc);

    var range = myNewDoc.getSelection();
    range.insertText("<h1>Hello world.</h1>", Word.InsertLocation.start);

    return context.sync().then(function () {
        myNewDoc.open();
        context.sync();
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

How can I edit the content of the new document instead?

[image: Example Recording]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you are new user, I recommend you read ["How to Ask a Good Question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Asking question properly will help you get better answers and help others be able to understand your question if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Home.html**

Replace `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js` to `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js`

```html
<script 
  src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" 
  type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

**Home.js**

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
    var myNewDoc = context.application.createDocument(getDocx());
    context.load(myNewDoc);

    //this is OK
    myNewDoc.properties.customProperties.add("code", "600000");

    // this is NG
    //var range = myNewDoc.getSelection();
    //range.insertText("123", Word.InsertLocation.start);

    return context.sync().then(function () {
        myNewDoc.open();
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    })
}).catch(errorHandler);
```

Comment: This seems to clear up the correct way to open the document, but it isn't clear how this answers your original question. How would does this add "Hello World" to the newly created document?

Comment: How to pass document name with opened document? Kindly suggest.